# I need to know how to echo a nested variable in batch

Tags: windows

I am trying to make a generator and it is suppose to give an output like `1` or `0`.

```
set var1=%var2%
set var3=1
set var4=%var2%
:genloop
set /a var4%var3%=%random%* 1 / 32768 + 1
set /a var3=%var3% + 1
echo %var4%var3%%
if "%var3%"=="%var4%" goto done
goto genloop
```

I can't get `%var4%var3%%` to have an output of `0` or `1` it gives an output of `var41` `var42` `var43` and so on instead of `1` or `0` so I need to know how to echo a nested variable

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `enabledelayedexpansion`.

```
set var1=%var2%
set var3=1
set var4=%var2%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:genloop
set /a var4%var3%=%random%* 1 / 32768 + 1
set /a var3=%var3% + 1
echo !%var4%var3!
if "%var3%"=="%var4%" goto done
goto genloop
```

|